# maximum error of a near-minimax approximation

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to find the maximum error in the degree $n$ near-minimax approximation to $g(t)=\tan^{-1}(t)$, $0 \leq t \leq 1$ for $n=1,\ldots,6$.  Does anyone know of a formula to find this?  The book doesn't give a formula and it kind of vague about how to find it.